# How to replicate CAPICOM SignedData.Sign() method in C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb6, certificate, capicom

I need to write a test harness for an existing Classic Asp website that uses VB6/CAPICOM components. The aim is to recreate the result of SignedData.Sign() so I can POST this to the Classic Asp website where it will decode the payload using CAPICOM.

VB6 CAPICOM for reference

```
Function SignContent(ByVal strXmlToSign As String) As String
    Dim strSignedString As String
    Dim objSign As SignedData ‘ From CAPICOM library
    Set objSign = New SignedData
    objSign.Content = strXmlToSign
    strSignedString = objSign.Sign
    Set objSign = Nothing
    SignContent = strSignedString
End Function
```

I've been using the CAPICOM docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signeddata-sign) as a guide

C# equivalent

```
public string Sign(string dataToSign)
{    
    ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataToSign));

    // Create a new, nondetached SignedCms message.
    SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo);

    // get cert from store by Serial Number
    X509Certificate2 cert = GetCertificateBy("my-cert-serial-number");
    CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(cert);

    // Sign the message.
    signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer);

    // Encode the message.
    var encoded = signedCms.Encode();

    // mimic default EncodingType; CAPICOM_ENCODE_BASE64 Data is saved as a base64 - encoded string.
    return Convert.ToBase64String(encoded);
}
```

So far the C# generated signature cannot be decoded by the CAPICOM component.

Comment: You wrote "recreate the result of SignedData.Sign()" but I assume you meant "SignedData.SignContent()" instead?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include sample output of both the VB6 and C# versions?

Comment: @DaveInCaz the method is sign see docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signeddata-sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of detective work I have managed to send a message to the endpoint that can be decoded the CAPICOM component. The working solution is below:

```
public string Sign(string dataToSign)
{
    // Default to SHA1; required if targeting .Net Framework 4.7.1 or above
    AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.UseInsecureHashAlgorithms", true);

    // The dataToSign byte array holds the data to be signed.
    ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(dataToSign));

    // Create a new, nondetached SignedCms message.
    SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, false);

    X509Certificate2 cert = GetCertificate();

    CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(cert);

    // Sign the message.
    signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer);

    // Encode the message.
    var encoded = signedCms.Encode();

    // mimic default EncodingType; CAPICOM_ENCODE_BASE64 Data is saved as a base64 - encoded string.
    return Convert.ToBase64String(encoded, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);
}
```

Summary of changes:

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.UseInsecureHashAlgorithms", true);
```

If .NET Framework 4.7.1+ is targeted (my app is targeting .NET 4.7.1) SHA256 is enabled by default for these operations. This change is necessary because SHA1 is no longer considered to be secure. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/retargeting/4.7-4.7.1#security)

```
ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(dataToSign));
```

Changed from Encoding UTF8 to Unicode.

```
return Convert.ToBase64String(encoded, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);
```

Use the line breaks option to match Capicom output.

Comment: Instead of the AppContext switch to reset the default, you can just manually assign `signer.DigestAlgorithm = new Oid("1.3.14.3.2.26");`

Comment: @bartonjs thanks for that. I as unaware. Is there a list of valid values? Why does "1.3.14.3.2.26" = SHA1?

Comment: [Object Identifiers (OIDs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_identifier) are hierarchically assigned number sequences.  1.3.14.3.2.26 means SHA-1 because ITU and ISO say so: http://oid-info.com/cgi-bin/display?oid=1.3.14.3.2.26&action=display.  The OIDs for MD5, SHA(-2)-256, SHA(-2)-384, and SHA(-2)-512 are all valid, Windows may also accept other digest algorithms it knows about.